# Which of the following options is true about Softmax Function?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, softmax

S1 and S2 are two statements with respect to SoftMax function, Choose the correct option:

S1: It is a function that turns a vector of K real values into a vector of K real values resulting a sum equal to 1.

S2: It can be used in a classifier only when the output classes are mutually exclusive.

Options :

1. S1 is true and S2 is false
2. S1 is false and S2 is true
3. Both S1 and S2 are true
4. Both S1 and S2 are false

Comment: Although the answer is correct, this looks like a copy-paste from a homework assignment. You should start by doing your own research instead of posting the entire question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't see a single line of code here. This type of question is more appropriate for Stats SE, AI SE or DS SE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

The correct option is `3: Both S1 and S2 are true`

**Why S1 is correct ?**

`Softmax` is a function that finds the probabilities of all the classes such that they sum to 1.

**Why S2 is correct ?**

If we are using a softmax, in order for the probability of one class to increase, the probabilities of at least one of the other classes has to decrease by an equivalent amount.

That means they have to be mutually exclusive.

**Due to this property we use `softmax` function in `multi-class` classification but not in `multi-label` classification.**

Instead we use `sigmoid` function for `muli-label` classification.